# Find descriptor in csv file then give it a value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-loc

Very new here, as in started yesterday with everything. I am working on a way to pull out one of four categories of weather from this csv file. VFR, MVFR, IFR, LIFR are the categories which every row in the csv should have.

```
import pandas as pd

ap1 = input('Airport 1: ')
ap2 = input('Airport 2: ')
cat = pd.read_csv('https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.csv', skiprows=5,
                    index_col='station_id', usecols=['station_id', 'flight_category'])


ap1_cat = cat.loc[ap1]
ap2_cat = cat.loc[ap2]

if ap1_cat == 'VFR':
    print('Green')
elif:
    ap1_cat == 'MVFR':
    print('Blue')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

I basically want to say, if flight_category is VFR Print 'Green' etc
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real issue is incorrect use of `loc` you have not specified that you want to select `flight_category` column so you are getting a structure that is both the `station_id` and the `flight_category`.  Personally I add the categorisation to the Dataframe then get it with `loc`

```
cat = pd.read_csv('https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.csv', skiprows=5,
                    index_col='station_id', usecols=['station_id', 'flight_category'])
df = cat.reset_index().merge(pd.DataFrame([{"flight_category":"VFR","Color":"Green"},
                        {"flight_category":"MVFR","Color":"Blue"}]),
         on="flight_category").fillna("Fail").set_index("station_id")
ap1 = "PKWA"
ap2 = "MMTO"
print(f"{ap1}: {df.loc[ap1,'Color']} {ap2}: {df.loc[ap2,'Color']}")
```

**output**

```
PKWA: Green MMTO: Blue
```